Tracing a transient but recurring process on Linux server
I administer an Ubuntu server for my research team. I have recently noticed that, occasionally, a process (using multiprocessing) will appear for a second or two that utilizes all available CPUs on the system. As we regularly need to utilize multiprocessing ourselves, this can be quite interruptive.
The problem is, I can't seem to figure out what exactly is triggering the process or where it's being run. Here's an example of what I can see (for example when using htop or watch).
root      962212  532  0.0 2759060 91168 ?       Rsl  07:41   0:05 python run.py start-queue

However, the process (and all of its cousins) is too transient to have time to identify it by its PID and do anything. Also, there are many run.py scripts on the system, but there are none in the root user's home directory. I can't seem to find any reference to that command in /etc/systemd/system services either. Even more confusingly (to me at least) is that for the root user, there is no local python (i.e. which python returns nothing), so I'm assuming that it's running from a virtual environment(?). root doesn't have any conda or venv installed, though, either...
I've tried (amateurishly) to use auditd and strace, but haven't been able to come up with anything helpful. For example with strace I was able to see processes attaching and exiting, but that's about it:
$ sudo strace -f -e execve -p $(pgrep -f 'python run.py start-queue') 2>&1 | tee python_trace.log

$ less python_trace.log
...
strace: Process 965533 attached
strace: Process 965534 attached
strace: Process 965535 attached
[pid 965474] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 965473] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 965475] +++ exited with 0 +++
...

Really scratching my head on this one!

Looking under /proc/<pid> may tell you in which directory the process is being run from.

@BobGoddard thanks for the tip. If the processes are terminated in a second or two, what can I still find in /proc/<pid> that would give me this information?


Use one of extrace, forkstat, or execsnoop[.bpf] to watch all process creation events system-wide. These will show you the immediate parent of every fork/exec. (Both extrace and forkstat use the "netlink connector" and do not require the server to have BPF or any tracing features.)
extrace: https://github.com/leahneukirchen/extrace (uses netlink connector)
forkstat: https://github.com/ColinIanKing/forkstat (uses netlink connector)
execsnoop 1: https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/execsnoop (uses kprobes)
execsnoop 2: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/execsnoop.py (uses BPF)

If you are able to notice the process in ps, then add the UNIT and/or CGROUP columns so that it would display which systemd unit and/or which kernel cgroup the process is in. As processes do not normally escape their cgroups, this should tell you the service responsible.
For example, watch "ps -ax -o pid,cmd,unit,cgroup | grep python"
or watch "ps -C python -o pid,cmd,unit,cgroup".



Your suggestion for adding the UNIT and CGROUP columns to the ps watcher gave me the clues I needed to find the culprit. Thanks!
